# exception_handling_C++_xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, exception

The following code throws the exception perfectly fine in Visual Studio 2010:

```
        #include <iostream>
        #include <cmath>
        using namespace std;

        int perfectSquare(double sq, int nu);

        int main()
        {
            double num;
            double squareRoot;
            int perfectSq;

            cout << "Enter the a number: ";
            cin >> num;

            try
            {
                squareRoot = sqrt(num); 
                perfectSq = perfectSquare(squareRoot, num);
                cout << "The square root is: " << perfectSq << endl;
            }

            catch(char * exceptionString)
            {
                cout << exceptionString;
            }

            cout << "BYE." << endl;
        //  system("PAUSE");
            return 0;
        }


        int perfectSquare(double sq, int nu)
        {
            int temp = sq;
            if (sq != temp)     //clever test; if square root IS NOT an INT
            {
                throw "not a perfect square.\n";
            }
            else
            {
                return sq;
            }
        }
```

However, in Xcode, it will not resume and it keeps hitting a breakpoint in the debugger.  For example if I inpute 33 (not a perfect square), the following error is displayed:
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)

It should "throw" this line:  "not a perfect square." and the  program should terminate (like in VS 2010).  I don't want to enable exception breakpoints in Xcode as I just want the program to run all the way to the end without debugging.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are throwing is a string literal, which in XCode seems to be a `const char*`, not a `char*`

Comment: Quick fix.  Didn't realize the difference from VS.  This did it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually throwing a `char *`, you are throwing a `const char *`. Change the exception catch to

```
catch(const char * exceptionString)
```

and it should work.

All literal strings in C++ are equivalent to pointers to a constant string, i.e. `const char *`.

Comment: Yeah, it shouldn't have worked in Visual Studio.  I like that Xcode was more strict, because it is a mistake to neglect the const.

Comment: Actually, a string literal is of type `char[N]`, mostly for historical reasons. You should treat it as a `const char[N]` though. So on the one hand, XCode's behavior seems to be not correct, but on the other hand, you should catch `const char*` anyways.